# Как изменить данные одной компоненты из другой React?

Tags: reactjs

Есть две компоненты, я хочу изменить фрагмент из `h1` по клику. Не знаю, насколько правильно делаю, наверное нужно через `setState`. Не уверен, что правильно понял как его использовать.

```
import React from 'react';
import '../index.css'
import Cover from './Cover'

class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        state = {
            isClicked: false
        }
        this.changeName = changeName.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main">
                <input className="input" placeholder="Username" />
                <button onClick={this.changeName} className="submit-button">Submit</button>
            </div>
        )
    }

    changeName = () => {
        this.setState({
            isClicked: true
        })
        Cover.username = document.getElementById('input').nodeValue
    }
}

export default Main

 //----------------------------------------------------------------

import React from 'react';
import '../index.css'

class Cover extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.username = 'username';
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="cover">
                <img className="logo" src="./assets/logo.svg" />
                <h1 className="header">Welcome on board, {{username}}!</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Cover
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать все просто. Начнем с дочернего компонента, а именно с `userName`, если вы хотите его менять внутри родителя, то я бы положил его в стейт родителя, а в дочерний компонент передавал как `props`. Тогда код станет немного более понятен.

Тогда в дочернем компоненте нам не нужен конструктор. Что будет в дочернем компоненте тогда (рекомендую при именовании использовать `camelCase`):

```
import React from 'react';
import '../index.css'

class Cover extends React.Component {    
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="cover">
                <img className="logo" src="./assets/logo.svg" />
                <h1 className="header">Welcome on board, {this.props.userName}!</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Cover;
```

Тогда как в родителе будет следующий код:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../index.css'
import Cover from './Cover'

class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        state = { 
            isClicked: false,
            userName: 'default name' 
        };
        this.changeName = changeName.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main">
                <Cover userName={this.state.userName} />
                <input className="input" placeholder="Username" />
                <button onClick={this.changeName} className="submit-button">Submit</button>
            </div>
        )
    }

    changeName = () => {
        this.setState({
            isClicked: true,
            userName: document.getElementById('input').nodeValue
        })
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Обратите внимание на следующие правки, которые я внес.

1. Класс `Cover` перестал иметь конструтор
2. Класс `Cover` внутри `render` метода имеет отрисовку имени из `props`
3. Класс `Main` внутри `changeName` метода записывает `userName` в свой стэйт
4. Класс `Main` внутри `render` метода имееет `<Cover userName={this.state.userName} />` отрисовку дочернего контрола с передачей пропсы.
5. Класс `Main` внутри конструктора добавлен стейт по-умолчанию `userName: 'default name'` для первого значнеия, чтобы при вызовер `render` метода не упала ошибка по отсутсвию `this.state.userName`